# Probability that a string of $5$ characters from set$\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ contains exactly one '$a$', given that it contains at least one vowel

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is a past paper exam question.
It doesn't have a mark scheme, so I was hoping somebody could check this answer for me. It's non-calculator, but I don't expect that affects the method used.

My solution is based on the accepted answer here: [Combinatorics question about english letters (with consonants and vowels)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246687/combinatorics-question-about-english-letters-with-consonants-and-vowels)

Let P(A) be the probability that the string contains exactly one '$a$'
Let P(B) be the probability that the string contains at least one vowel.

Need to find $P(A|B) = \frac {P(B|A) \cdot P(A)} {P(B)}$

Total combinations of $5$ letters from the set of $5 = 6^5$

$P(A)$ can be satisfied by a single 'a' being in any of 5 places - $5 \choose 1$ , and the other 4 places in the string can be any of 5 characters - $4^5$. Then $P(A) = \frac {5 \cdot 4^5} {6^5}$

$P(B)$ :
There are $6^5$ total combinations, as above. 
Of these, There are $4^5$ with no vowels.
Then, $P(B) = \frac {6^5 - 4^5} {6^5}$

Now, $P(B|A) = 1$, since $A$ is sufficient for $B$ - there must be a vowel if there is an 'a'

So, $P(A|B) = \frac {P(B|A) \cdot P(A)} {P(B)} = \frac {P(A)} {P(B)} = \frac {\frac {5 \cdot 4^5} {6^5}} {\frac {6^5 - 4^5} {6^5}}$

--

This seems to make sense, but I'm not completely convinced about my calculations, particularly for $P(A)$.

Would anybody be able to either confirm my solution or point out where I went wrong?

Comment: It looks pretty good to me but I think the numerator of $P(A)$ is $ {5 \choose 1} 5^4$ as there are 5 different characters for the remaining 4 places as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analysis looks good. I would like to suggest exactly the same thing, in a marginally different style.

In the notation that you use, we want $\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.  This is a more basic formula, and does not prejudge how we will compute the top. A "Bayes formula" approach to the computation may not be optimal. And several conditional probabilities in one expression can lead to confusion. (They didn't in your case.)

Note that $A\cap B$ says exactly one $a$ and at least one vowel. So it says exactly one $a$. The **location** of the $a$ can be chosen in $\dbinom{5}{1}$ ways. For each way, the remaining $4$ places can be filled in $5^4$ ways. Thus
$$\Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{\binom{5}{1}5^4}{6^5}.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better approach. I'd just been revising and the Bayes formula was the last one I'd gone over, definitely should have gone with this one. Accepting this because it's definitely how the question should be approached.

Comment: You are welcome. I found that students who tried to use Bayes as a universal tool in conditional probability problems often ran into trouble. (You didn't.)

Comment: Yep, I can see where I'd end up going round in circles if P(B|A) hadn't been so trivial. Out of interest though, would situations where Bayes isn't appropriate basically be where P(A) is difficult/impossible to find, but P(AnB) is given or solvable? Clearly it's easier to just use your approach, I'm just wondering where you'd want to specifically avoid Bayes?

Is it a case of use Bayes only if you can't find P(AnB)?

Answer (score 2):

"the other 4 places in the string can be any of 5 characters - $4^5$"

That is the only place where I see an issue. 4 places and 5 characters means $5*5*5*5 = 5^4$. Otherwise, everything else looks good as long as you simplify in the end (combine the $5*5^4$ and cancel out the two $6^5$.

Comment: Thanks! Good spot, and that of course makes the end a bit simpler too.